# Determining an angle bisector in a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Let $K$ be a circle with center $B$ and $A,C,D$ points on the circle. Further let $\overline{BE}$ be the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AC}$.

Then it happens to be that the line $\overline{DE}$ is the angle bisector of $\sphericalangle CDA$, but how does one proof this?

Comment: This is essentially the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angles subtended by an arc at the center of a circle are double those at the circumference:

$$\angle ADE = {1\over 2}\angle ABE = {1\over 2}\angle EBC = \angle EDC$$

Comment: OK, but maybe you should mention angles subtended by an arc at the center of a circle are double those at the circumference.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.